# Convert a date column with space to r date column

Tags: r

I have following column which contains year and month but with a space between them:

```
date
2000 Oct
2000 Nov
2000 Dec
2001 Jan
2001 Feb
2001 Mar

[1] 2000 Oct 2000 Nov 2000 Dec 2001 Jan 2001 Feb 2001
```

I want to convert this to a date column

I tried following: 
`as.Date(df$date, "%YYYY %mm")` but it gave me all NA(s)

Comment: I think you mean `%Y %b`, but regardless a year and a month are not a date. Either paste on a day, or look at `yearmon` objects in **zoo** or **xts**, I can't remember which.

Comment: You could do: `as.Date(paste0(df$date," 1"),"%Y %b %d")`, where df is your data frame

Comment: @R.Schifini Fantastic this is a perfect answer. Which it was not mark duplicate because it was not the same question. Can you put this as an answer i want to give credit for this answer. Someone could benefit in future.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis The second answer at the duplicate shows the "paste a day on and then use `as.Date`" method that you praise so highly. The only difference is that you need `%b` not `%m`.

Comment: Yes, pasting a specific day was among the answers of the question. Upvote that answer if you found this useful.